# How to change a line from a text file (PHP)

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

Text file(text.txt):

```
#Minecraft server properties
#Tue Sep 23 18:07:26 CEST 2014
generator-settings=
op-permission-level=4
allow-nether=true
level-name=world
enable-query=true
allow-flight=false
announce-player-achievements=true
server-port=25565
query.port=25565
level-type=DEFAULT
enable-rcon=false
force-gamemode=false
level-seed=
server-ip=
max-build-height=256
```

How to replace the value of some line, such as these:

```
server-port=25565
```

Replace with:

```
server-port=25585
```

But no to find 'server-port=25565' and replace with 'server-port=25585'
It is found that the lines in which the server port and to allocate a value that needs to be replaced.

Example:

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("text.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    ...
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

EDIT:
And when finded this and saved replace the text file.

Comment: Use [`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

Comment: [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) should work?

Comment: @EricSSH Not always the same value of server-port, I want to find a 'server-port' and to replace value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your format looks suspiciously like a PHP configuration file `(.ini)`, why not using the **[parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)** function?

```
$ini = parse_ini_file("text.txt");
echo "<pre>".print_r($ini,TRUE)."</pre>";
```

or

```
echo $ini["server-port"];
```

Change it:

```
$ini["server-port"] = 25585;
```

Save again your .txt file with:

```
$f = fopen("text.txt","w");
foreach($ini as $k=>$v) {
   fwrite($f,$k."=".$v.PHP_EOL);
}
fclose($f);
```

You may need to change your `#` comments symbol though with `;`

**UPDATE**

```
$lines = file("text.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
// modify
foreach($lines as &$line) {
   $val = explode("=",$line);
   if ($val[0]=="server-port") {
      $val[1] = "25585";
      $line = implode("=",$val);
   }
}
unset($line);

// save again
$f = fopen("text.txt","w");
foreach($lines as $line) {
   fwrite($f,$line.PHP_EOL);
}
fclose($f);
```

Comment: #Minecraft server properties
#Tue Sep 23 18:07:26 CEST 2014

This is deleted after save and values 'true' and 'false' also deleted.

Comment: It seems `parse_ini_file` removes booleans. You can change to `0` or `1` which are the `.ini` boolean alternative. The `#` produces errors and you must use `;` which is the comment symbol for `ini` files

Comment: But this is no `.ini` file, this is config file for minecraft server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) or [`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

```
<?php

$file = "file.txt";

$content = file($file);

foreach ($content as $line_num => $line) {
    if (false === (strpos($line, 'server-port=25565'))) continue;

    $content[$line_num] = "server-port=25585\n";
}

file_put_contents($file, $content);
```

---

Before

```
#Minecraft server properties
#Tue Sep 23 18:07:26 CEST 2014
generator-settings=
op-permission-level=4
allow-nether=true
level-name=world
enable-query=true
allow-flight=false
announce-player-achievements=true
server-port=25565
query.port=25565
level-type=DEFAULT
enable-rcon=false
force-gamemode=false
level-seed=
server-ip=
max-build-height=256
```

After

```
#Minecraft server properties
#Tue Sep 23 18:07:26 CEST 2014
generator-settings=
op-permission-level=4
allow-nether=true
level-name=world
enable-query=true
allow-flight=false
announce-player-achievements=true
server-port=25585
query.port=25565
level-type=DEFAULT
enable-rcon=false
force-gamemode=false
level-seed=
server-ip=
max-build-height=256
```

---

**Edit**

You can modify the `$new_port` variable to anything you want.

```
$path = "file.txt";
$new_port = 25585;
$content = file($path);

foreach ($content as $line_num => $line) {
    if (false === (strpos($line, 'server-port'))) continue;

    $content[$line_num] = "server-port=$new_port\n";
}

file_put_contents($path, $content);
```

Comment: The value of server-port is not always the same or (25565)

Comment: @FilipET So just find `25565` and replace with `25585`, correct?

Comment: No, I need to find a `server-port` and then extract the value of `server-port` and replace it.

Comment: @FilipET Do you want it to be replaced in the file, or just echo'ed on screen?

Comment: Only to be replaced in the file

Comment: @FilipET There's something I'm obviously missing. What I posted finds `server-port=25565` inside the file and replaces it in the file with `server-port=25585` - Is there some kind of added functionality you want to use? Or do you mean, find just a line in a file that contains `server-port` and replace it with something else, say `server-port=xxxxx`?

Comment: 'find just a line in a file that contains server-port and replace it with something else'

Comment: @FilipET Ok. I see you found your solution, am glad to hear that. Keep the accepted answer, but do have a look under my **Edit**, it may serve you also. *Cheers*